# aws s3 object, objects in the same bucket different life cycle is possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

> Assume there is a shared bucket: `Bucket_A`
>
> 2 IAM users: `user_A` and `user_B`.
>
> `user_A` uploaded: `images/image_A.png` <-- will expire in 30 days
>
> `user_B` uploaded: `images/image_B.png` <-- will never expires

Is it possible to configure as objects in the same bucket has a different life cycle?

Answer (score 0):

A lifecycle rule can apply to all objects in a bucket or to a subset of objects in a bucket based on the Filter element that you specify in the lifecycle rule.

You can filter objects by key prefix, object tags, or a combination of both (in which case Amazon S3 uses a logical AND to combine the filters).

In your case, it might be sensible to have different prefixes e.g. images-30days/a.png or simply tag the relevant objects with Expires=30day.